# TypeScript 2.1 Custom Elements

Tags: typescript, custom-element, typescript2.1

TypeScript 2.1 Apparently now has support for writing custom html elements (["What's new in TypeScript - 2.1"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#typescript-21))

However I have been unable to find any documentation on how this is supposed to work.

Can anyone provide an explanation on how this is supposed to work, ideally with examples?

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently this is **not** possible, when targeting *ES5* with TypeScript. The Custom Elements API V1 **needs** ES6/ES2015-style classes. However if you target *ES5* with TypeScript (for compatibility with IE 11 for example) *all* classes get transpiled to functions.

This is not a TypeScript limitation, but a limitation of the Custom Elements API V1 [itself](https://github.com/webcomponents/polyfills/tree/master/packages/custom-elements#es5-vs-es2015).

You have two options:

1. Target ES2015 with TypeScript and thus drop IE11 support altogether
2. Target ES5 with TypeScript and use:

   - a polyfill for the Custom Elements API, that supports ES5
   - a [shim](https://github.com/webcomponents/polyfills/blob/master/packages/custom-elements/ts_src/native-shim.ts) that allows the native Custom Element API to be used with ES5 (and thus transpiled TypeScript)

The release notes for TypeScript 2.1 are misleading; it is not a TypeScript issue at all. See this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12949) for more background.

Answer (score 5):

The only thing I can find on that page about custom elements is that the new way of handling `super()` calls in ES5 [*allows* TypeScript to be used to define custom elements](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#use-returned-values-from-super-calls-as-this).

This just means that you can now write regular ES2015 code to define a custom element, and the new TypeScript compiler will output the *correct* ES5 code for it. Previously, the outputted code would not do the right thing with the `super()` call, which would break custom element classes.

There are no TypeScript examples for this, since this isn't really specific to TypeScript. It's just following the custom elements standard:

```
class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.foo = "bar";
    }

    doSomething() {
        console.log(this.foo);
    }
}

customElements.define("my-custom-element", MyCustomElement);
```

Comment: That you. That will definitely make my life easier. It's quite obvious now you have said it. Just a shame they didn't include a example like that in the docs

Comment: I get following error
`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'HTMLElement': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function`

Comment: This is very cool! But it only works with HTMLElement. Why can't I extend HTMLDiveElement or HTMLAnchorElement ?

Comment: @Kokodoko This is not the scope of TypeScript or OPs question. :) For further information have a look at https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements#extendhtml or _raise your voice_ at https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/509

Comment: You are wrong. TypeScript can't output _correct_ ES5 code for the Custom Element API V1, because the API itself does only work with ES2015 classes. TypeScript has no special logic to work around it, nor is it technically possible. The information on the release notes are misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Forget IE11 and use es6 (https://caniuse.com/?search=es6). All you have to do is to change the **target** line in your tsconfig.json to:

```
//tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
  }
}
```

To learn more about this file see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html